# Phonegap - Automatically redirecting to a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, mobile, phonegap

I want to develop a mobile app using the Web stack and package with phonegap.
My index.html page will contain a login form. I have a js function `checkLoggedIn()`;
that checks if user is logged in by looking for a localStorage variable.

**Challenge** : I want `index.html` to automatically redirect to `member.html` if `checkLoggedIn()` 
returns `true`; otherwise it won't redirect and just stays on `index.html`, that means `checkLoggedIn()` will run on `index.html` on load.
I don't know what kind of event to fire or how to fire it to achieve this.

Comment: So u need a autologin feature where when ever user close the app and open it again it has to redirect to the inner page right?

Comment: Something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my working code for the auto login feature hope this works for both android and ios

Below is the code  for login button after entering the user name and password

```
  $('#login').click(function () {
    var userName = $('#Username').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();

    if (userName == "" || password == "") {
        window.plugins.toast.showLongBottom("Please enter a valid data");
        return false;
    }

       var options = { dimBackground: true };
    SpinnerPlugin.activityStart("Loading...", options); 

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: xxxxxx.xxxx.xxxxx,
        data: "uid=" + userName + "&pwd=" + password + "",

        success: function (resp) {
            SpinnerPlugin.activityStop();
            if (resp.status != 0) {
                if (resp.RoleId == 1) {

                    mash.Session.getInstance().set({
                        userId: resp.sno,
                        userName: resp.Name,

                    });
                    var session = mash.Session.getInstance().get();
                    window.open('Add.html', '_self', 'location=no');

                    // Create session. 
                    var today = new Date();
                    var expirationDate = new Date();
                    expirationDate.setTime(today.getTime() mash.Settings.sessionTimeoutInMSec);
                }
                else {
                    SpinnerPlugin.activityStop();
                    mash.Session.getInstance().set({

                        userId: resp.sno,
                        userName: resp.Name,

                    });
                    var session = mash.Session.getInstance().get();

                    var username = userName;
                    var password = password;

                    window.localStorage.setItem("uname", resp.Name);
                    window.localStorage.setItem("pass", password);
                    window.localStorage.setItem("sno", resp.sno);

                    window.localStorage.setItem("RoleId", resp.RoleId);


                    window.open('Main.html', '_self', 'location=no');
                    //window.plugins.toast.showLongBottom("Login Successfull");
                    // Create session. 
                    var today = new Date();
                    var expirationDate = new Date();
                    expirationDate.setTime(today.getTime() + mash.Settings.sessionTimeoutInMSec);

                }

            }
            else {

                SpinnerPlugin.activityStop();
                window.plugins.toast.showLongBottom("Please Enter valid Username and password");
                SpinnerPlugin.activityStop();

            }

        },
        error: function (e) {
          SpinnerPlugin.activityStop();
            window.plugins.toast.showLongBottom("Invalid Data");
            SpinnerPlugin.activityStop();
        }
    });


});
```

after this in the index.html use onload handler  fillpassword() to use this below function

```
function fillpassword() {

    if (window.localStorage.getItem("uname") != 0) {


        mash.Session.getInstance().set({

            userId: window.localStorage.getItem("sno"),
            userName: window.localStorage.getItem("uname"),


        });
        if (window.localStorage.getItem("RoleId") != 1) {

            document.getElementById('Username').value = window.localStorage.getItem("uname");
            document.getElementById('password').value = window.localStorage.getItem("pass");

            window.open('Main.html', '_self', 'location=no');
        }
    }
    else {
        //alert("Yes")

    }
}
```

the above code works and all u need to maintain a session

Comment: Where is the onload handler

Comment: @bodesam fillpassword() is my onload handler. when ever i close my app and repopen again it wont ask for login directly i will redirect to another given page

Comment: how do you get that function to run automatically on page load

Comment: @bodesam Firstly i am saving the username and password value in session and then in to the localstorage. in the next step where user terminate the app then again he  opens it then from we take  uname and password  values from local storage and logs the page automatically and we will use  <body onload="fillpassword()">

Comment: <body onload="fillpassword()"> that's what I'm looking for.You are sure this works?

Comment: @bodesam This is a working piece of code in my project and u need to maintain session for this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153786/discussion-between-bodesam-and-madpop).

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
if(checkLoggedIn()) window.location = "member.html";
```